# RxJs: Incrementally push stream of data to BehaviorSubject<[]>

Tags: angular, rxjs5

Basically I'm trying to inflate `BehaviorSubject<[]>` with array of data which will be loaded in chunks.

`BehaviorSubject<[]>` will be added with new chunk of data (like `Array.push`) but I don't want to use another array to store and add to `BehaviorSubject.next` because this will cause rendering to take too long as the data grow over time.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use `getValue()` method to achieve what you want to do.

Example:

```
data = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);

addData(foo:any):void{
  // I'm using concat here to avoid using an intermediate array (push doesn't return the result array, concat does).
  this.data.next(this.data.getValue().concat([foo]));
}
```

Comment: `getValue()` made my day. Thanks.

Answer (score 30):

Instead of using `concat`, you can instead use the spread operator:

```js
data = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);

addData(foo: any): void {
  this.data.next([...this.data.getValue(), ...foo])
}
```

I've found this to be a bit more readable than a straight `concat`

Comment: This was perfect! works for me as Supamiu answer fails to me not sure why.