# How to make api shouldn't be loaded if there's no data in angular using global.getData

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

here's the code:

```
loadNextBatch() {
    console.log('scrolldown');

    this.pageIndex = this.pageIndex + 1;
    this.global.getData(`/conditions/latest?start=${this.pageIndex}&length=${this.pageSize}`)
      .pipe(take(1)).subscribe(res => {

        const newBatch = res['data'];
        if (newBatch.length === 0) {
          return false;
        }

        this.tempThermometer.next(this.tempThermometer.getValue().concat(newBatch));
      console.log(this.tempThermometer);
      });
  }
```

what I'm trying to do here is when there's no data from the `/conditions/latest?start=9&length=4` it still running to `start=11 ...etc` how to make it stop.
when there's no data it should be stop in `start=8` because on `start=9` there's no data anymore.

How to stop it from the `start=8` but when there's a data on `start=9` it can be load. but if there's no data on `start=9` it shouldn't be loaded.

also the problem when I scroll down it continued to ``` start=11`` ```start=12`it should be stop on`start=8`cause there's no data on`start=9```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RxJs: Incrementally push stream of data to BehaviorSubject<\[\]>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44272402/rxjs-incrementally-push-stream-of-data-to-behaviorsubject)

Comment: @developer033 it doesn't work. it will just add an item undefined

Comment: Put the next statement in else clause of newbatch=0

Answer (score 0):

Defined a global variable and wrap the API call in an `if condition` seems logical right?

```
canLoadNextbatch = true;

loadNextBatch() {
  console.log('scrolldown');

  this.pageIndex = this.pageIndex + 1;
  if (this.canLoadNextbatch) {
    this.global.getData(`/conditions/latest?start=${this.pageIndex}&length=${this.pageSize}`)
      .pipe(take(1)).subscribe(res => {

        const newBatch = res['data'];
        if (newBatch.length === 0) {
          this.canLoadNextbatch = false;
        } else {
          this.tempThermometer.next(this.tempThermometer.getValue().concat(newBatch));
          console.log(this.tempThermometer);
        }
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: it still running

Comment: it still running even there's no data in ```start=9```